# How to understand ruby gsub "\\\\" return "\"

Tags: ruby, regex

Here is my code:

```
"/home/roroco".gsub(%r{/}, "\\") # => "\home\roroco"
"/home/roroco".gsub(%r{/}, "\\\\") # => "\home\roroco"
```

I think the later one should be `\\home\\roroco`, why is it `\home\roroco`?

this is my ruby version:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads $ ruby -version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: What version of ruby? It works for me.